# AJAX/ json returning null open cart

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, opencart

Hi Im attempting a simple `ajax` request but I keep getting a null value for `json`.

Here is my javascript...

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() { 
$('#donate-box-submit').on('click', function() {

    var donate_code = $('#charity-campaign-code').val();
    var donate_amount = $('#charity-campaign-amount').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=donate/donatenow',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            donate_code: donate_code,
            donate_amount: donate_amount
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {

        },  
        complete: function() {

        },          
        success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
            alert(json['test']);
        },
        error: function() {
        }
    });
   });

 });



</script>
```

and my php...

```
    public function donatenow() {

    $json = array(
    'test' => 'Output this text'        
    );


    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));     
}
```

I have also tried `echo json_encode($json);` just to rule out any issues with that OpenCart function, but the same issue is still there.

Comment: `console.log(json)` is missing a `;` at the end of line: `console.log(json);`. Checking the request in console are you able to see the response from PHP controller?

Comment: You're declaring $json twice. Remove the first one. Close the space after `array` in the second one.

Comment: thanks, I made those changes, but still showing as `null`

Comment: Ill edit the code now to reflect those just to rule them out

Comment: Can you visually confirm the json being output in the browser?

Comment: Sorry stupid question but what do you mean? Basically its saying "null" in firebug, and when I remove `['test']` from the javascript its alerting a box saying `null`

Comment: Go to the URL in your browser and confirm the test json is being output: index.php?route=donate/donatenow. Or check in the Net tab of Firebug and view the response to the ajax call. Confirm the json is being output. If so, eliminate the PHP code from the problem.

Comment: I dont think Im getting a response, if that makes sense, in the net tab, there is no response appearing, just param, headers, post, html, cache, cookies, apologies, Im still getting to grips with the concept

Comment: It may be $this->response->setOutput() is failing, but if echo json_encode($json); isn't showing a response either then it's likely donatenow() isn't being called.

Comment: Try using the full URL in  `$.ajax({ url:`

Comment: @logic-unit - You are correct that it's not being called - see why in my answer below

Comment: Its fixed now, thank you! you were right , the function wasnt being called, if logic-unit would like to answer it feel free, only because I had it fixed before seeing the answer below based on what they said

Comment: @JayGilford that would make sense, good catch. I'm not familiar with opencart.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it fixed. @JayGilford got the answer, it's fine to accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the route you are using to call the method. Not sure on exactly what class you are using as the controller, but there should be three parts to the route: `route=aaa/bbb/donatenow` where as you've got `aaa/donatenow`